# How to get lan ip address as output in arch linux (Manjaro)

Tags: linux, networking, lan, arch-linux, manjaro

I have a script which I used to use in ubuntu. It got my lan ip address using the command `hostname -I`. I would get an output like `192.168.1.xxx` as a string which I can use somewhere else.

However, with Manjaro, the command doesn't exist, when I tried `hostname -i`, (lowercase) but i get `127.0.1.1`. I even installed the dnsutils.

Is there a way I can get my lan address as an output from any command / tool in Manjaro?

Comment: By "lan IP address".. do you mean the gateway or YOU?  Are you familiar with `ifconfig` or `ip addr` .. to narrow down *stuff*.. look at the command lines (man) for these commands.

Comment: i meant ME not the gateway

Comment: those commands give me a whole lot of junk, i just need 1 line which is my own ip address on the LAN. so 192.168.1.90, the gateway is 192.168.1.254

Comment: Use `ip addr` or `ifconfig`.  The options go on and on (unfortunate for us) ... but for instance.. `ip a show eth0` .. `ifconfig | grep -A 1 'eth0' | tail -1 | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1`  or `ip -o -4 addr list eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1` .

Comment: "those commands give me a whole lot of junk" .. you are using the wrong operating system.

Comment: lol i mean i use these commands in other system to get information i need, its just that i had easier access to this function there. i guess things need to be done a bit manually here

Comment: Home in on `ip -o -4 addr list eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124358/discussion-between-anarchy-and-senor-cmasmas).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Linux *iproute2* tools have been supporting JSON output since 2017. This output is then easily parsable with the [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) utility (which is distributed in most distributions, including [Manjaro](https://software.manjaro.org/package/jq)) for use in scripts.

You can combine this with asking the kernel how it would choose to reach some well known address (eg: 8.8.8.8), and keep only the relevant part (among other information such as the gateway, the interface name etc.): the chosen local address (`"prefsrc"`) using a *jq* filter. No packet is emitted, it's just asking the kernel to resolve a route and give back the result:

```
ip -json route get 8.8.8.8 | jq -r '.[].prefsrc'
```

will give the result which won't be affected by any output peculiarities nor requires to know beforehand the interface name. This result is dynamic. For example if one then uses a VPN for all traffic, the previous command would return the new tunnel address instead.